# Ubuntu Core for Raspberry Pi Zero as a bitcoin Wallet

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I have recently come up with a plan of making a simple full computer hardware wallet for different crypto currencies out there using Raspberry Pi Zero W. Some of you might already know about the raspberry pi hardware used for embedded usage. But I am facing some insecurities and confusion regarding this.

Plan:

1. Basic but very secure minimal Linux distro.
2. Copay, Ethereum and Litecoin wallet software for three cryptocurrencies.
3. Use ubuntu-core with ubuntu-desktop-like GUI which is very user friendly.

I want a very minimal Linux distro which will run only some basic wallet applications and some custom software for backup and stuff I wanna code in C or C++. Whereas ubuntu-core itself is around 350MB+. Are all ubuntu-core packages needed for this kind of operation? Or is there any way to cut down these packages to reduce the vulnerabilities?

Comment: Thanks Zanna for editing the question. Any solution yet guys? It has been 5 days already.

Comment: Cutting down on the amount of packages you have installed on a system will not necessarily decrease vulnerabilities. Instead, focus on preventing the user from doing dumb things - disallow software install, block inbound connections, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an answer that is on-topic for Ask Ubuntu, the only thing we can say is to:

- use a Raspberry Pi 2 or 3 instead of a Zero
- install the [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 'classic'](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.27classic.27) ARM version on it
- Build (Build! Not install as you're running on an ARM)

  - [Copay](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48507/how-to-install-copay-desktop-wallet-in-ubuntu)
  - [Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu)
  - [Litecoin](https://gist.github.com/mediaupstream/5294957)
- for the three cryptocurrencies you want

because #1 in your question is [off-topic for Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) but on-topic in [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), a sister site of Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: There you go! Happy now? :D

Answer (score 1):

I already did a port of the trezor code for the raspberry pi zero to create a bitcoin wallet. The details of my project is here: https://www.pitrezor.com/

For the Linux platform, instead of using ubuntu I used [yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) as a customizable embedded distribution.